# Plot emotion development based on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am working on a face detection and emotional recognition project. I would like to plot the emotion developments on a plot like this figure [image]
Y-axis is the emotions and the X-axis is depending on the number of emotions registered (0 - len(emotions)). Any tips and ideas on this?
This is what I tried to do but it did not work, [image]

Comment: Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888) for more information. This leads to less guessing when it comes to determining the issue and can lead to better answers faster. Perhaps just the results of `print(df[df['Name'] == 'Jacki Chan'].to_dict())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate 'Happy' etc. to numbers, that's why you get the error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Happy'.  You can get all unique emotions into a list and use the list index to specify numbers for each of them, for a new numeric column in your df.  Here's one way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emotions': ['Happy', 'Disgust', 'Disgust', 'Happy']})

emotion_list = df['Emotions'].drop_duplicates().tolist()

for i, emotion in enumerate(emotion_list):
    df.loc[df['Emotions'] == emotion, 'emotion_as_number'] = i
    # or i + 1 if you want to start at 1 not 0
```

to get

```
  Emotions  emotion_as_number
0    Happy                1.0
1  Disgust                2.0
2  Disgust                2.0
3    Happy                1.0
```